# Extract a value of unfamiliar list

Tags: python

I was given a Python script helper for my simulation project. I printed a list `print event.connection.features.ports` that looks like this:

```
[port_no: 65534
hw_addr: aa:20:20:40:f8:48
name: s9
config: 1
state: 1
curr: 0
advertised: 0
supported: 0
peer: 0

, port_no: 1
hw_addr: 36:7c:47:6d:ba:8c
name: s9-eth1
config: 0
state: 0
curr: 192
advertised: 0
supported: 0
peer: 0
]
```

The idea here is that this list looks a strange list to me!! I don't even know how to extract a certain value based on an index since indices here are not clear (I assumed there are only 2 indices here since comma might be the separator here). My desired value to extract is `hw_addr` based on given `port_no`. For instance, if I want to `hw_addr` of `port 1`, I tried something like `port_no[1][1]` but this doesn't work. I used a loop to loop over this list as the following:

```
for i in event.connection.features.ports:
    if i.port_no == 1:
        print i.port_no[1][1]
```

This loop gives this error!

```
  File "/home/ahmad/pox/pox/Latency_Monitor.py", line 57, in _handle_ConnectionUp
    print m.port_no[1][1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Kindly, can someone give a hint? Thank you

Comment: It looks to me this is because someone defined the `__repr__` function on the elements in the list. Could you provide the error?

Comment: Yes! I will update the post with the Error. Thank you guys

Comment: Checking `type(i.port_no)` and `dir(i)` may help understand the real structure of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason while your list looks *weird* is because someone defined the `__repr__` function and thus defined how to print an element given the list is printed.

> I tried something like `port_no[1][1]`.

I would be surprised if that worked. `i.port_no` is, based on the fact that your tests succeeded, probably an integer. What you probably need to call is `i.hw_addr`. So something like:

```
for i in event.connection.features.ports:
    if i.port_no == 1:
        print i.hw_addr # not port_no[1][1]
        #or do something else with hw_addr
```

Comment: RIGHT! This worked. I haven't thought about that. Thank you very much,